# Shadowing variables in methods

Tags: java, scjp, shadowing

I was reading the certification book of Java 6. And there was an example about "Shadowing variables":

```
package scjp;

class Class1 {
    int number = 28;
}

public class Example {

    Class1 myClass = new Class1();

    void changeNumber( Class1 myClass ) {
        myClass.number = 99; 
        System.out.println("myClass.number in method : " + myClass.number);
        myClass = new Class1();
        myClass.number = 420;
        System.out.println("myClass.number in method is now : " + myClass.number);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Example example = new Example();
        System.out.println("myClass.number is : " + example.myClass.number );
        example.changeNumber( example.myClass );
        System.out.println("After method, myClass.number is : " +   example.myClass.number);
    }

}
```

And this is the result :

```
myClass.number is : 28
myClass.number in method : 99
myClass.number in method is now : 420
After method, myClass.number is : 99
```

My question is: 
If at the beginning, the variable 'number' is 28. When I use the method, it changes the variable to 99 and 420. But ..., when the method finish, why does the variable 'number' have a value of 99 instead of 28 ?
I thought it would have its original value (28).

Comment: It is so obvious things, that I recommend you begin at the beginning of OOP.

Comment: I'm not an expert as you, Sir. But thanks for answering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `changeNumber()`, the reference to `example` is copied and passed to the method. You change the value of `number`, which **modifies the referenced object**, then reasssign a new instance to `myClass`, **which does not affect the original reference** in `main`.

Everything goes as expected, then you exit the method. Back to the `main` method, you still have the primary reference to `example`, which was affected by the first reassignment (of `number`), but **not by the reassignment of `myClass`**. That's why you have 99, not the original 28.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your answer was very helpful. (Everyone else is in a bad mood today).

Answer (score 0):

You change the value of the instance you treat to 99; afterwards you create a NEW instance and modify that.

The newly created instance is discarded at the end of changeNumber() because it is no longer referenced.

Answer (score 0):

1- **from first line the number =28:**

`Main example = new Main();`///////Main call class1(**myClass**)---->which set **number=28**

2- `System.out.println("myClass.number is : " + example.myClass.number );`////the output here is (***myClass.number is : 28***)

3- `example.changeNumber( example.myClass );`///////in this method you will set **number=99** then print it (
***myClass.number in method : 99***
) , then creat new object( which mean the **number=28** , and the *number in previous object still =99*), the new object **(myClass = new Class1();)** will print (***myClass.number in method is now : 420)***

4- `System.out.println("After method, myClass.number is : " +   example.myClass.number)`;///// this line will print ***(After method, myClass.number is : 99)*** because this is from the first object created (myClass)